# I want to rewrite https://blog/home/post?read=example to https://blog/home/example with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have tried many methods but none has worked.
Blog is the name of the domain, Home is a folder in the domain and post.php is the page getting details from database.
So, in my domain, I have:
home/post.php

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ /post?read=$1 [L]    # Handle page requests
```

Above is the last code I used and it is not working. I'm getting a 404 error.

Comment: `home` is a root directory, `blog` is a domain, and `post` is a file?? Please put the content of the question in the question. Also clarify details of URLs and file. Current guess is you want `RewriteRule ^/?home/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+) /home/$1 [QSA,L]` or `.php` after `$1` if the file has an extension (which it should, unless you also are rewriting the rewrite)

Comment: I think the issue is exactly the rewriting to `/post`. What kind of ressource is `/post` meant to be inside your http server? Could it be you mean something like `/post.php`? Or that you have other, additional rules in place which you did not tell us about?

Comment: Where is the .htaccess file located?

Comment: The .htaccess is located in the root of the folder.

Comment: the /post is a php file that displays the details of a post based on the 'read' from my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ /post?read=$1 [L]    # Handle page requests
> ```
>
> The .htaccess is located in the root of the folder.

You seem to be ignoring the `home` subdirectory. (Although you've referred to both `home` and `Home` in your question - note that this is case-sensistive.) And if "`/post` is a PHP file" then you should presumably be rewriting to `post.php`, not simply `post`?

Note that Apache does not support line-end comments, as you are using here. (At best they get ignored, at worst they trigger a 500 error.)

If the `.htaccess` file is located in the document root, as you suggest then you would need to write the rule as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^home/([\w-]+)$ home/post.php?read=$1 [L]
```

The `\w` shorthand character class is the same as `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches the URL-path relative to the location of the `.htaccess` file.

If, on the other hand, the `.htaccess` file is in the `/home` subdirectory (ie. at `/home/.htaccess`) then you would write the rule like this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ post.php?read=$1 [L]
```

Note, there is no slash prefix on the *substitution* string.

Comment: It worked perfectly. 
Thank you so much.